# 2D Array File Reader

Tags: java, arrays, string

For my computer science class I'm making an website username/password program. I decided to use a 2D string array, and it hasn't been working out the best. I tried to make a file reader to read the logins that get written but I keep getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error. My file reader code is below, and also included is my login input code. I am just starting Java so I have very basic programming knowledge.

```
private void fileReader() throws FileNotFoundException {

    File inFile = new File(filePath);


    try {

        Scanner freader = new Scanner(inFile);

        while (freader.hasNextLine()) {

            for (int j = 1; j <= pass.length; j++) {

                pass[j][0] = freader.nextLine();

                pass[j][1] = freader.nextLine();

                pass[j][2] = freader.nextLine();

            }
        }

        freader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(1);

    }
```

Login input:

```
private void input() throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {



    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length; i ++){

            System.out.println(i);

            if (i == pass.length){
                add();
            }

            c.print("Please enter the website: ");

            pass[i][0] = c.readLine();

            c.print("Please enter your username: ");

            pass[i][1] = c.readLine();

            c.print("Please enter your password: ");

            pass[i][2] = c.readLine();

            while (true){

                c.clear();
                    synchronized (c) {
                        c.println("To continue adding logins, press C. To exit the program press ESC.");
                        c.println(pass[i][0] + " " +  pass[i][1] + " " +  pass[i][2]);
                    }
                if (c.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_C)){
                    break;
                }
                else if (c.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)){
                    fileWriter();
                    pass();
                }

                Thread.sleep(10);

            }

    }




}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Where did you initialize your 2D array ?

Comment: Where is the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ? In what line ? What is `pass`? How big is it ? What type is it ?

Comment: @UDKOX it starts off being 1 line, but increases by 1 each time the user adds a new login.

Comment: @T.Claverie I initialize it in the declaration, `private String pass[][] = new String[1][3];`

Comment: `for (int j = 1; j <= pass.length; j++)` I think this is wrong, try `for (int j = 0; j <= pass.length; j++)`. 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @UDKOX when I changed it for j = 0, it seemed to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is because of this:

`for (int j = 1; j <= pass.length; j++) {
    pass[j][0] = freader.nextLine();
    pass[j][1] = freader.nextLine();
    pass[j][2] = freader.nextLine();
}`

An array starts from 0.  By making j = 1, you are starting on the second array in the group, you need to start with 0 and read up to but not including the array length.

Comment: Oops, I forgot I had it at 1. I was trying all sorts of things to try and fix it. I changed it to `for (int j = 0; j < pass.length; j++) {

     pass[j][0] = freader.nextLine();

     System.out.println(pass[j][0]);

     pass[j][1] = freader.nextLine();

     System.out.println(pass[j][1]);

     pass[j][2] = freader.nextLine();

     System.out.println(pass[j][2]);

    }` (dont mine the print, that was just to make sure it was printing the right values)